# xpath for href containing word in url find by needle

Tags: url, xpath, partial, cpu-word

Looking for solution for this XPATH problem

```
<a href="www.aaa.bbb/bla**mykey**_bla/xoxoxo">
```

XPATH for this link

How do I locate this element with 'mykey' part in it !?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) should be used here:

```
//a[contains(@href, "mykey")]
```